# Unity3D Instantiating as GameObject

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject

> My code look like that:
>
> ```
> if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire2")) {
>         GameObject transparent = Instantiate (building, new Vector3 (0, -10,0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
> }
> ```
>
> Where building is public GameObject which I add through unity
>   Inpsector. After using right click GameObject is instantiated, but
>   transparent variable has null instead of the instantiated GameObject.
>   If I change type of transparent to Object and I remove 'as GameObject'
>   cast, everything works good.

**Ok, I find out what was wrong**. My building wasn't GameObject, it was Building (class which inherits MonoBehaviour, so have gameobject in itself). Now I instantiate building.gameobject and everything is ok.

Comment: is building in your prefabs folder? Did you add building to your script?

Comment: I said building appears in game view, but transparent gets null as a value instead of reference to the spawned gameobject. Building is in the prefab folder and added to script in inspector.

Comment: Problem is that Instantiate don't want to return other type than Object even with casting to GameObject or Transform.

Comment: try `GameObject transparent=((Transform) Instantiate(stuff)).gameObject;`

Comment: Everything is OK now? Congratulations! But I think maybe post an answer to tells other that you found the solution is better than edit your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I initiated 'building' as a Building class (Building is my own class and inherits MonoBehaviour), not as a GameObject so unity had problem to put Building into GameObject. It's looks like that now:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire2")) {
    GameObject transparent = Instantiate (building.gameobject, new Vector3 (0, -10,0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

}